# How to modify an existing bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

Having read [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56268/17237) answer on how to modify an existing bibliography style if you only want to apply small changes (that is, if you want to avoid defining a completely new style using `latex makebst`), I was wondering whether it is possible to achieve this *without* having to create a new `.bst` file: Can I use an existing bibliography style (say, `plain`) and make changes to it directly in my `.tex` document?

The motivation behind this is that I would like to be able to quickly change the underlying bibliography style (e.g. from plain to abbrv) while keeping the modifications (e.g. font variations) without having create a new modified style file.

So I am wondering whether anything like this can be achieved, used in a `.tex` document:

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
% modifications to the style come here, e.g. modify FUNCTION {date.block}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you always have to create a new `.bst` file. BibTeX reads the `.bst` file when doing formatting, but has no direct interaction with the `.tex` file (it scans the `.aux` file for citation and style names, but that is all). You could use the `filecontents` environment to embed a `.bst` file inside a `.tex` file, but this is probably not that useful as `.bst` files tend to be large (1000+ lines is typical). Note that you don't have to generate a `.bst` file from scratch: making a renamed copy and altering the required parts is doable (ask about your modification in a separate question if needed).

One of the reasons for the development of [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) is precisely because it leaves formatting to the `.tex` file. As such, `biblatex` styles can be adjusted in the LaTeX document. On the other hand, `biblatex` uses a completely separate set of standard styles to traditional BibTeX, so a transition may not be trivial, depending on your requirements.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into moving to `biblatex` and create a new `.bst`in the meantime.