# Changing the location of 'year' in typeset bibliographic entries when using abbrvnat.bst

Tags: bibtex, natbib

How do you relocate the position of 'year' in the reference list using natbib and abbrvnat.bst? I want it to come in parentheses just after author name for any type of entry, like so:

J. Smith (2010) *A Book*. Publisher, city.

I already have made changes to my .bst file which I have relocated in my file directory, so I know how that works. I just can't relocate the date globally.

(I know it would be smarter using biblatex, but at present I have too long a file with citations which needs to be changed.)

Comment: There is no *global* way to relocate the output of the `year` field. You'll have to edit separately the type-related functions `article`, `book`, `booklet`, `inbook`, etc etc, to relocate the `format.date "year" output.check` and `format.date output` directives. In many of the type-related functions, you will also have to suppress the `new.block` directives that follow the printing of the authors' or editors' names. Finally, you will also need to edit the `format.date` function, since you want parentheses around the value of `year`.

Comment: see @Mico's answer to an alternative query, where he demonstrates how to make similar types of customisations to the bibliography citation styles: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56268/78565
It may not be exactly the same as your question, but it is close enough. I think you will get some clarity from it!

Comment: Also, this question is almost similar, except for the citation style & the parentheses: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9192/78565