# Change position of "year" in typeset bibliographic (using siam-letters style in memoir)

Tags: bibliographies, memoir

I am using memoir for my thesis and using siam-letters for my bibliographystyle.

The default position for "year" is at the end in each reference, which I hope to move just after the author(s).

I have noticed some similar questions, such as [Changing Year position in natlib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9192/changing-position-of-year-in-natbib-with-plainnat-style) or [Change Year Position for  abbrvnat.bst](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247518/changing-the-location-of-year-in-typeset-bibliographic-entries-when-using-abbr), but the soultions there seems not working for my case (memoir and siam-letters.bst).

Please kindly advise me.

Edit. My minimal code

```
\documentclass[twoside, openbib, a4paper,12pt,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\begin{document}
Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus.\cite{SankaranImpactTradeLiberalization2010a}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{siam-letters}
\bibliography{Test}

\end{document}
```

My Test.bib:

```
@article{SankaranImpactTradeLiberalization2010a,
  timestamp = {2018-02-22T23:19:42Z},
  title = {Impact of {{Trade Liberalization}} on {{Employment}}: {{The 
  Experience}} of {{India}}'s {{Manufacturing Industries}}},
  number = {Query date: 2018-02-23},
  journal = {Indian Journal of Labour~\ldots{}},
  author = {Sankaran, U and Abraham, V and Joseph, K J},
  year = {2010}
}

@article{BackerGlobalValueChains2011,
  timestamp = {2018-02-22T23:19:43Z},
  title = {Global {{Value Chains}} : {{Preliminary}} Evidence and Policy 
Issues Ppt},
  number = {May},
  journal = {Review of Business and Economic Literature},
  author = {Backer, Koen De},
  year = {2011}
}
```

Comment: As always, please post a minimal working example to give helpers a test case. I am pretty sure this is unrelated to `memoir`.

Comment: Question is why you are using this style. If somebody told you to use it, don't change it. If you don't have to use it, you are better off with `biblatex`.

Comment: (I have just added the minimal code). I have attach memoir since I have gone too far with this class for my thesis. Please kindly advise me.

Comment: `siam-letters` is a numerical style where it is common to have the year at the end. You seem to want an author-date (harvard style) bibliography, which would be uncommon to be numbered.

Comment: I understand the difference between numerical and author-date style. The later provides the format I need but also seems to make such info "double". I am, therefore, seeking for a "combined" style, whereas the number is still useful for easily searching. Please kindly advise any better solution if this "combined" way is not possible. Many thanks.